# Checking empty textEdit

Tags: java, android, registration, textutils

I'm trying to program a simple register application, the user have to fill some fields, where some of them are obligatory. So, I need to check if the user write the info there. I'm doing this:

```
    for(RequireFields r : RequireFields.values()){
        if(boolValue()){
            switch (r.getField()) {
                case "name":
                    System.out.println("Name");
                    break;
                case "surname":
                    System.out.println("Surname");
                    break;
                case "pass":
                    System.out.println("Pass");
                    break;
                case "email":
                    System.out.println("Email");
                    break;
                case "street":
                    System.out.println("Street");
                    break;
                case "city":
                    System.out.println("City");
                    break;
                case "zip":
                    System.out.println("Zip");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where boolValue() return the status of TextUtils.isEmpty(Field), but this part I don't know how to do it, RequireFileds for now is an enum:

```
public enum RequireFields {
    NAME("name",1),
    SURNAME("surname",2),
    EMAIL("email",3),
    PASS("pass",4),
    CITY("city",5),
    STREET("street",6),
    ZIP("zip",7);

    private final String field;
    private final int position;

    RequireFields(String field, int position) {
        this.field = field;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

}
```

I put a number with the name, so I can use an iterate for.
Any ideas or a easy way to do this?

PD: This is the code for two fields that I used on other app:

```
    ssid.setError(null);
    pass.setError(null);

    String SSID = ssid.getText().toString();
    String PASS = pass.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PASS) && !openWifi) {
        pass.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_pass));
        focusView = pass;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(SSID)) {
        ssid.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_ssid));
        focusView = ssid;
        cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this for checking empty EditText...

```
if (editTextName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
{
      // show message/toast for empty name
} 
else if (editTextSurname.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
{
     // show message/toast for empty Surname
} 
else if (editTextEmail.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))  
{
     // show message/toast for empty Email
}
else 
{
     // If above all conditions are false means all fields are not empty so put your action here 
}
```

Hope this help..

Comment: Yes, but i want to do that without using too much "if else if" ... I have 7 editText, that's the best way?

Comment: See you must have to check every EditText if is empty or not, so at least one time you have to check every editText, so may be its better by my point of view. if you find better  then please share that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not catch what you want. Below is what I had used

add below code to your requireFields

```
    private static final SparseArray< RequireFields > _map=new SparseArray< RequireFields >();
static {
    for (RequireFields cmd: RequireFields.values())
    {
        _map.put(cmd.position,cmd);
    }
}
public static RequireFields valueOf(int value) { 
  RequireFields field = _map.get(value);
  if (field==null) {
    Log.d("RequireFields","RequireFields position "+value+" not found");
  }
  return field; 
  }
```

then you can use switch like

```
switch(RequireFields.valueOf(value){
    case NAME:
        .......    // your handler
        break;
    case SURNAME:
        ....
}
```

Hope this help